# Does Chrome respect the X-DNS-Prefetch-Control header?

Tags: web-application, dns, chrome, content-security-policy, dns-prefetch

If my web page returns `X-DNS-Prefetch-Control=off`, will Chrome do DNS prefetch for links like these?:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://www.spreadfirefox.com/">
```

I know Firefox and Chromium respect this header, but I'm not sure if Chrome does as well.

I'm asking because I would like to disable DNS prefetching on certain secure pages on my website to protect against this kind of vulnerability: https://blog.compass-security.com/2016/10/bypassing-content-security-policy-with-dns-prefetching/

Comment: [This doc](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/dns-prefetching) says yes, but I can't promise it's authoritative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after some experimentation:

My page contains a link that does DNS prefetching to an arbitrary domain:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://aaaaaaaaaaa@(new Random().Next(11111)).ba@(new Random().Next(11111)).com">
```

I set the X-DNS-Prefetch-Control header to "off" and added a <meta> tag to be extra safe:

[image: Http header and meta tag]

Unfortunately chrome still does a DNS call to that domain, even with a strict Content Security Policy.

[image]

My page's content security policy that does not allow calls to any external domains:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; form-action 'self';
```

So it seems like Chrome does **not** respect the X-DNS-Prefetch-Control header. I'm using Chrome v64.0.3282.167

Answer (score 1):

The `X-DNS-Prefetch-Control` HTTP response header controls DNS-prefetching of `<a href>` elements on hover. It has nothing to do with `<link rel="dns-prefetch">` mechanism.

Comment: Source: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/dns-prefetching/#dns-prefetch-control

> The DNS prefetch control setting applies only to hyperlinks and not to the manual prefetch mechanism.

Though I wouldn't say "it has nothing to do"